# how to add attribute rel nofollow on tag a with regex

Tags: php, regex, rel

how to add attribute rel nofollow on tag a with regex

Sample:

```
<a href="http://www.test.org/5521" rel="follow">test1</a>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5522" rel="external">test1</a>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5523">test1</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="http://www.test.org/5521" rel="nofollow">test1</a>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5522" rel="nofollow">test1</a>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5523" rel="nofollow">test1</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a DOM parser would be a more natural solution here:

```
$html = <<<STR
<html><body>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5521" rel="follow">test1</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5522" rel="external">test1</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5523">test1</a>
</body></html>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/27XG3)

With `$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");`, you get all the `a` nodes, and with `$link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');`, you set the `rel` attribute regardless whether it was present or not.

Output:

```
<html><body>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5521" rel="nofollow">test1</a><br>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5522" rel="nofollow">test1</a><br>
<a href="http://www.test.org/5523" rel="nofollow">test1</a>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Remove All Rel from tag a

```
$result = preg_replace('@rel="(.*)"@U', '', $html);
```

Step2: Add Rel Nofollow on taf a

```
$result = preg_replace('@<a(.*)>@U', '<a$1 rel="nofollow">', $result);
```

Comment: Why not use DOM?